# Separately managing obiects from lists in spring 3 mvc + jsp web application

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, model-binding, spring-3

After thinking a lot, this is the best question title I could find. Not that representative, I'm sorry :-(.

By the way let me explain the problem.
I have to implement an administration panel. It displays a table where every line contains a user with his roles and account status. You can see the idea sketched in the following image

[image: image of the user management form]

now, my problem is about managing the backing model object:

1. I have to pass a list of users to populate the administration panel but
2. I have to bind *each user* to a model object and
3. I have to submit each user separately.

I found many tips for managing the table as a whole so that a single button submits all the users at the same time, but what I want to do is populating the table with a list and managing every list record (the user) *separately*.

I thought to manage each line with javascript to keep trace of the modified values and to use them to build a uri like `http://authority/app/user_management/{user_id}/{is_locked}/{is_admin}/.../`. The uri will be triggered by the corresponding submit button, but I prefer to avoid this approach.

Moreover, to populate the table with the correct checkbox value it is necessary to have a binding enstablished.
Any advice?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you going to use AJAX? If not and you are submitting the whole page, you could pass an index on click on an individual submit button and persist just that row. This will also help the user retain rows which he/she may have changed, but not submitted yet when the page refreshes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply dvlpr. AJAX was my first guess. I just wanted to know if there was a trick (or something) to do all the work with JSPs and controller logic only.

Comment: If you have only a handful of parameters then you can pass them as request parameters to a controller mapped to an appropriate backing object and force binding on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **separate form** for each row with a User object as a Model. You will have simple 'updateUser' handler with User object in input parameters list. 
As I remember it could be a User you are iterating through in your foreach, but I need to check it with the real example..) At least you can use simple form and pass 'id', 'isLocked', etc. as request parameters.

```
<!-- Inside foreach loop -->
<form action="/updateUser" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${user.id}"/>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="isAdmin" value="Is Admin" checked="${user.isAdmin}"/></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

And something similar on server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseDTO updateUser(@RequestParam String id, @RequstParam boolean isAdmin) {
// your update logic
}
```

Comment: so I'll have a `<form:form>` object for each user in the table. There is a little issue about this approach: what will I declare as `commandName` attribute value? I must be able to address a single list item, I can't figure out how to do so.

Comment: I have updated the answer, pretty sure that it is possible to pass User but don't have ability to check it now. Will update later.